# Oracle: REGEXP_REPLACE | Replace any username value with given value

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I have below value in a column in a table.
`{"host":"SOME_SERVER_NAME","port":22,"Username":"SOME_USER_NAME","Password":"SOME_PASSWORD","fileNamePattern":"SOME_FILE_PATTERN"}`

I want to replace the host, Username, Password values to my own values. So the above column field will become like:
`{"host":"MY_NEW_VALUE","port":22,"Username":"MY_NEW_VALUE","Password":"MY_NEW_VALUE","fileNamePattern":"MY_NEW_VALUE"}`

How do I do this using `regexp_replace`?
Something like:
`select regexp_replace(column_name, '"Username":"[\D*]"','"Username":"MY_NEW_VALUE"')
from table_name;`

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use regular expression, rather than the simpler `replace()` function? Are the existing values different in multiple rows?

Comment: `regexp_replace(column,'"Username":"\D+?"','"Username":"MY_NEW_VALUE"')`

Comment: @AlexPoole - No specific reason. But as these host, username, password values will be unknown, I thought regexp_replace would be a better option.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz If a quoted string has an escaped double quatation mark in it then that will fail.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         column_name,
         '"(Username|host|Password)":"(\\"|[^"])*"',
         '"\1":"MY_NEW_VALUE"'
       )
FROM   your_table
```